# Which coordinates are inversely proportional in the picture?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, coordinate-systems, inverse-function

[image]

> Which coordinates are inversely proportional in the picture ?

I found it between $F$ and $A$; $L$ and $M$

Is it correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: There is one set of $5$ points that have a common $k$ for $y=k/x$.

Comment: @Joffan Can you explain me? Please.. :(

Comment: You say you found that $F$ and $A$ show an inverse proportion (between their $x$ and $y$ values) - this is correct. This means that they have the same value $k$ when solving  $y=k/x$. What is that value? And what other points have the same value?

Comment: Is this language *Azerbaijani*?

Comment: Yess)) I'm Azeri :) thank you for answer Dear teacher.

Comment: @Joffan I missed point C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points which satisfy an inverse proportionality relation are in red and the equation is $xy=6$

[image]

Comment: I understood thankk you so much..I missed point C